# jquery DropKick reload contents on ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, plugins, reload, jquery-dropkick

Is there anyway to reload or sync a DropKick dropdown after it's being loaded...
I'm refering to this beautiful jquery plugin

http://jamielottering.github.com/DropKick/

What I have is a state, city ajax loading dropdown that needs to be dynamic...

I have tried with

```
$('#select').removeData("dropkick");  
then 
$('#select').dropkick();
```

has anyone  done this ?
please help

Answer (score 1):

I think you should remove the dk_container div before before calling dropkick().

Try:

```
$('#select').removeData("dropkick");   
$('div.dk_container').remove();   
$('#select').dropkick();
```

It works for me with DropKick v.1.0.0.

hth